# how to set default value for edittext is 1 number

Tags: java, android

I have a piece of java code.
but when I run the program, if I don't enter enough value fields for the lonx variables, I get an error.
please show me how I can run the program if the input EditText still doesn't have enough fields. thank you.

As shown in the picture, if I don't enter 4 Editext, when I press the button, the value of the text will not be displayed, but I will exit the application.

[image]

---

I want the program to understand that if I don't enter it, the edittext will be treated as 0

I tried to put `android:text("0");` in each EditText but it didn't work

```
package com.example.test2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class thitlon extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText lon1,lon2,lon3,lon4,lon5,lon6,lon7,lon8,lon9,lon10,lon11;
    Button btquydoilon;
    TextView textxoloc1,textnac2;

    DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thitlon);

        btquydoilon = findViewById(R.id.btquydoilon);
        lon1 = findViewById(R.id.lon1);
        lon2 = findViewById(R.id.lon2);
        lon3 = findViewById(R.id.lon3);
        lon4 = findViewById(R.id.lon4);
        lon5 = findViewById(R.id.lon5);
        lon6 = findViewById(R.id.lon6);
        lon7 = findViewById(R.id.lon7);
        lon8 = findViewById(R.id.lon8);
        lon9 = findViewById(R.id.lon9);
        lon10 = findViewById(R.id.lon10);
        lon11 = findViewById(R.id.lon11);
        textxoloc1 = findViewById(R.id.textxoloc1);
        textnac2 = findViewById(R.id.textnac2);

        btquydoilon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                thitxoloc();
                thitnac();

            }
        });
    }

    private void thitxoloc() {
        double tlon1 = Integer.parseInt(lon1.getText().toString());
        double tlon2 = Integer.parseInt(lon2.getText().toString());
        double tlon3 = Integer.parseInt(lon3.getText().toString());
        double tlon4 = Integer.parseInt(lon4.getText().toString());
        double tlon5 = Integer.parseInt(lon5.getText().toString());
        double tlon6 = Integer.parseInt(lon6.getText().toString());
        double tlon7 = Integer.parseInt(lon7.getText().toString());
        double tlon8 = Integer.parseInt(lon8.getText().toString());
        double tlon9 = Integer.parseInt(lon9.getText().toString());
        double tlon10 = Integer.parseInt(lon10.getText().toString());
        double tlon11 = Integer.parseInt(lon11.getText().toString());
        double thitxoloc = ((tlon5 + tlon6 +tlon7) * 0) + (tlon1 * 0.5) + (tlon2 * 0.6) + (tlon3 * 0.67) + (tlon4 * 0.6) + tlon8 + (tlon9 * 0.25) + (tlon10 * 0.3) + tlon11;
        textxoloc1.setText("thit: " + currency.format(thitxoloc) + " kg.");
    }

    private void thitnac() {
        double tlon1 = Integer.parseInt(lon1.getText().toString());
        double tlon2 = Integer.parseInt(lon2.getText().toString());
        double tlon3 = Integer.parseInt(lon3.getText().toString());
        double tlon4 = Integer.parseInt(lon4.getText().toString());
        double tlon5 = Integer.parseInt(lon5.getText().toString());
        double tlon6 = Integer.parseInt(lon6.getText().toString());
        double tlon7 = Integer.parseInt(lon7.getText().toString());
        double tlon8 = Integer.parseInt(lon8.getText().toString());
        double tlon9 = Integer.parseInt(lon9.getText().toString());
        double tlon10 = Integer.parseInt(lon10.getText().toString());
        double tlon11 = Integer.parseInt(lon11.getText().toString());
        double thitnac = (tlon1 * 0.5) + (tlon2 * 0.4) + (tlon3 * 0.33) + (tlon4 * 0) + (tlon5 * 0.6) + (tlon6 * 0.3) + tlon7 + tlon8 + (tlon9 * 0.25) + (tlon10 * 0.3) + tlon11;
        textnac2.setText("THa: " + currency.format(thitnac) + " kg.");
    }


}
```

Comment: Seems you are puting wrong tag,`javascript` is not `java`

Comment: I write program using android studio software. use java language

Comment: Can you share your layout file?

Answer (score 0):

Use below method instead of Integer.parseInt()

```
private double parseDouble(EditText text){
    try{
        return Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0D;
    }
}
```

Replace:

```
double tlon1 = Integer.parseInt(lon1.getText().toString());
```

with:

```
double tlon1 = parseDouble(lon1);
```

You can get a default value zero by getting all EditText values using above method.

Comment: Thank you verymuch for this answer.
I'll check it out and test it out